# SQL report with subreport not showing on page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I have created a SQL report using Visual Studio (also works when using Report Builder).  The report consists of the main report with sub reports in it.  When running the report via Visual Studio or Report Builder or publishing to the Report Server, it works fine and the main report and sub reports show correctly.

I have an ASP.Net MVC application which displays the report but it also allows the user to specify a where clause before running it.  When the report is run via the MVC application, it shows only the main report and then says:

> The subreport 'sub' could not be found at the specified location
>   [MVC application direcotry] Please verify that the subreport has been
>   published and that the name is correct.

even though the report is there.

The following is a snippet of the code which loads and displays the report:

```
        if (ReportFileName != null && ReportFileName != "")
        {
                ViewBag.Title = "Reporting";
                reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
                reportViewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                reportViewer.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                reportViewer.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);
                SqlConnection conx = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ConnectionString);
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(Basequery, conx);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                adp.Fill(ds.Tables[0]);

            reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = ReportFileName;

        }
        reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

        reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("ReportDataSet", ds.Tables[0]));
        reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
        ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;
        return PartialView("ReportView");
```

is there something that im missing?

Comment: Probably the subreport name is wrong, it happend to me too. Go to subreport properties and check if you point to right report location

Comment: wish it was that easy.  report name is correct.  when i built the report/run the report i need to select the sub report to use.